# iFrame differentiating Mainpage from everything else using Regular Expression Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, iframe

I want to return a value in a function depending on the Location URL from within an iFrame.

The value is 1 if the iFrame is on the main site page, and 2 if anywhere else on the site.  Currently it only returns 1.

I'm new to RegEx and have a feeling it is my syntax.

Any help would be hugely appreciated!

Here is what I have so far:

```
  var LocationURL = document.referrer;

  re = new RegExp("/^(http:\/\/)?(www.)?(website.co.uk/)[a-zA-Z0-9/.]+$/");
  bFound = re.test(LocationURL);

  function getJoinPageLoc()
  { 
   return (bFound == true)? 2 : 1; 
  } 

  console.log(getJoinPageLoc());
```

I am trying to allow it to start with http://www.  or just www.  or nothing.

I am assuming that any other location on the site will start with / so I am using website.co.uk/  as an absoloute (obviously website will be the actual website), followed by anything else (to make sure it's not the main page).

I hope this makes some sense!

Edit:

Still trying. Have tried this also but still not working:

```
  re = new RegExp("/^(https?:\/\/)?(www\.)?website\.co\.uk/([a-zA-Z0-_9/\.]+)&/");
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with document.referrer picking up the wrong frame >_<

Have had to, insteadm pass in a parameter through the top location and work this the other way round. Which in retrospect is much simpler >_<